# Extruding around corners distortion

Tags: 3d-view, extrude

I work a lot with extrusion, but I cant figure out how to prevent distortions in corners like the Picture shows below.

can I prevent this, or do I always have to fix it manually?

[image: Corner distortion]

Answer (score 3):

Activate the *Offset Even* option in the *Operator Box*?

[image]

Comment: OMG thank you I have been searching so long for this.